# Indexing a string in Swift

Tags: string, swift

I'm trying to find out how many letters 2 words (which are known to have the same length and to be in roman characters only) have in common. To do so, I have the following code

```
var sameplace = 0
for n in 0..<(word1.utf16Count){
    if word1[n] == word2[n]{
        sameplace += 1
    }
}
```

However, I get an error when trying to index the strings with `n`, which is an `Int`. The error is, specifically, `'Int' is not convertible to 'String.Index'`.

Is there a way to index a string with an int, without having to convert it to an `NSString` every time first? Can I make the loop generate n as a `String.Index` instead of an `Int`? What's the most "swiftic" way to do this?

Comment: Your code count only identical characters at the *same position*. Is that what you intended?

Comment: @MartinR I think yes, because he's adding one to the variable `sameplace`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution which does even work with all kinds of Unicode characters,
grapheme clusters etc:

```
let word1 = "abcd"
let word2 = "axcy"

var sameplace = 0
for (c1, c2) in Zip2(word1, word2) {
   if c1 == c2 {
       sameplace++
   }
}

println(sameplace) // 4
```

A Swift `String` is also a `Sequence` of its characters, and
`Zip2` returns a sequence that iterates over the two given sequences in parallel.

Comment: Quite impressive that `Zip2` does the right thing, treating a `String` as an array of `Characters`, even if you mix a grapheme cluster with a ASCII character in the same position it still works: "aabcd" and "axcy".

Answer (score 3):

If you really need to access a character at a specific index, you can use the `advance` function with the `startIndex` of the string:

```
var sameplace = 0
for n in 0..<(word1.utf16Count){
    if word1[advance(word1.startIndex, n)] == word2[advance(word2.startIndex, n)]{
        sameplace += 1
    }
}
```

However, this is terribly inefficient because it iterates to n for every iteration through the for loop. It is also not ideal to assume the utf16 count is correct.

Instead, you can iterate the `String.Index`s more manually:

```
var sameplace = 0
var index1 = word1.startIndex
var index2 = word2.startIndex
do {
    if word1[index1] == word2[index2]{
        sameplace += 1
    }
    index1 = index1.successor()
    index2 = index2.successor()
}
while(index1 != word1.endIndex && index2 != word2.endIndex);
```

You could also potentially make use of a templated function to help you iterate over two sequences (this will allow any Sequence, not just strings):

```
func iterateTwo<S: Sequence>(seq1: S, seq2: S, block: (S.GeneratorType.Element, S.GeneratorType.Element) -> ()) {
    var gen1 = seq1.generate()
    var gen2 = seq2.generate()
    while (true) {
        var possibleElement1 = gen1.next()
        var possibleElement2 = gen2.next()
        if possibleElement1 && possibleElement2 {
            block(possibleElement1!, possibleElement2!)
        }
        else {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can simply do:

```
var sameplace = 0
iterateTwo(word1, word2) { (char1, char2) in
    if char1 == char2 {
        sameplace += 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, these other answers work, too, but there is a way to do this which gets you pretty close to the way you want to do it:

```
var sameplace = 0
for n in 0..<(word1.utf16Count) {
    if Array(word1)[n] == Array(word2)[n] {
        sameplace += 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that creating an 2 new arrays for the entire words each time is going to be computationally expensive. Even creating the arrays once is more expensive than is necessary but you should at least create the arrays once outside of the loop.

Comment: Also note that `Array(word1)` gives you an array of `Character` which might have a length that is different from `word1.utf16Count` (try `word1 = "abcd"`).

Comment: @MartinR Well, the asker said that he knows the words will only contain Roman characters, so that shouldn't be a concern in this case.