# How do you iterate over values resulting from Zip2 in Swift

Tags: swift, iterator

I would like to use a for-in loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually really easy. Just use `Array(Zip2)`. After that you can iterate over it:

```
let theZip = Zip2(["Hi", "up?", "that"], ["whats", "Not", "much"])
let myZipArray = Array(theZip)

//without array
for single in theZip{
    println(single)
}

//with array
for single2 in myZipArray{
    println(single2)
}
```

Comment: You don't need to create an array from the Zip2 generator (and your code does not use the array at all :)

Comment: How efficient is this, namely having to create another object (an Array) everytime I want to iterate over the results of Zip2?

Comment: @user678392: As I said, you don't have to create an array in order to iterate over the Zip2. Here is another example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24974583/indexing-a-string-in-swift/24974702#24974702.

Comment: Where is the documentation on Zip2? How did you know that you could do for single in theZip { ...}?

Comment: That actually was just a mistake by me. I didn't take the myZipArray to do the for loop by mistake. But it's cool that it also works. I've added the second version with the array also.